# Sequence of matrices converging to a positive semidefinite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a sequence of symmetric matrices $A_n\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ converging to a symmetric semipositive definite matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ under the Frobenius norm:

$$
||A_n-A||_F \to 0,\,\,for\,\,n\to \infty
$$

I have no guarantees that $A_n$ is positive semi definite, but I can calculate, for each $n$ a value $\epsilon_n$ such that
$$
||A_n-A||_F<\epsilon_n
$$
At this point, am I allowed to say that after a certain $N_0$, also $A_n$, for $n>N_0$ needs to be positive semidefinite?
Is there any theorem in this direction?

------Edit:

In particular I am interested in the non-trivial case where all the components of $A$ and $A_n$ are positive: $A_{i,j}>0$, ${(A_n)}_{i,j}>0$,
and $A$ has at least a positive eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Suppose $A=0$, and $A_{n}=-\frac{1}{n}I$.  The sequence of $A_{n}$ matrices converges in Frobenius norm to $A$ but none of them are positive semidefinite.

If $A$ were positive definite, then you could reach the desired conclusion.

The OP has since modified the question to include a restriction that all of the elements of the matrices be positive.  The OP also wants A to have at least one positive eigenvalue.   It's still easy to find a counter example.  For example, let

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0.01 \\
1 & 1 & 0.01 \\
0.01 & 00.01 & 1 
\end{array}
\right]$

and

$A_{n}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1+1/n & 0.01  \\
1+1/n & 1 & 0.01 \\
0.01     &  0.01 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$

Comment: I see we have had the same idea !

Answer (score 0):

No, for any dimension $n$, there are counter-examples with matrices

$$M_k=diag(-1/k,-1/k,\cdots,-1/k)$$

(which have all their eigenvalues negative), which converge to the semi definite positive matrix $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can be said something in the case when all the components of the involved matrices are positive (see the edit)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not particular to matrices as such.

Consider the sequence of scalars $A_n = - {1 \over n}$; these converge to $A = 0$ which is positive semi definite, but clearly none of the $A_n$ are.